# What does "it is being published" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-continuous

Which of the following does the phrase **It is being published** mean?

> 1) It is now available in bookstores.
>
> 2) It will soon be published.

Answer (score 5):

If it's now available in bookstores, you want to say:

> It **is** published.

Your sentence is more appropriate when the book has begun the process of being published, but it isn't available in bookstores yet.

Comment: If I may ask, is '*It is being published*' an informal way to say '*It is in the process of being published*'?

Comment: It is not really informal, but yes, it is the same as "It is in the process of being published". It is like the -ing in "I am dancing" --> I am currently in the process of dancing.

Comment: Why *being published* does not mean it's available in bookstores? *Pope John Paul II's notes (that) are being published as a book*. It certainly means that the book **is available**. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, you've misunderstood.

Comment: @MaulikV "being" refers to the process. "being published" means that the book is getting prepared, so it is not finished yet. Something that "is published" is finished, but even that doesn't necessarily mean that the book is in bookstores yet - it is now in book form and ready to be distributed to bookstores. So "published" does not in itself mean "available", especially when the process is not even finished!

Comment: so *getting published* = *being published*

Comment: That is correct! If I may, was it the "being" or the "published" that had you confused? (I realise you are not the OP, but your response might be helpful in understanding the OP's confusion as well).